# Adjectives - superlative and comparative to positive form

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

Is there any way to obtain positive form of comparative/superlative adjective?
eg. better -> good; biggest -> big.
I use the newest version of NLTK.

Comment: this software seems to do the opposite: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#comparative
maybe it can be reverse-engineered from the source code here: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/media/pattern-2.5.zip
(although I'm not sure if it uses NLTK)

Comment: nvm, it's starting in line 1028 of `pattern2-5/pattern/text/en/inflect/_init_.py` but it's heuristic... :(

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem, searched the web with no answer, then discovered that it actually can be done with the `WordNet` `lemmatizer` in `nltk`.

Recall that [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/wndb.5WN.html#toc3) has those simplified pos tags:

```
n    NOUN 
v    VERB 
a    ADJECTIVE 
s    ADJECTIVE SATELLITE 
r    ADVERB
```

among which the adjective tags, `a`and `s`, can be used for the normalization.

```
>>> from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> wnl.lemmatize('biggest', 'a')
u'big'
>>> wnl.lemmatize('better', 'a')
u'good'
```

Here the second parameter does the magic trick. If left blank, it defaults to `'n'`, or `wordnet.NOUN` in`lemmatize()`. Similarly, it should be put explicitly as `'v'` or `'r'` for normalizing verbs and adverbs, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the wordnet gloss/definition from NLTK as such:

```
from ntlk.corpus import wordnet as wn

for ss in wn.all_synsets():
  if "(comparative of" in ss.definition:
    comp = ss.definition.split("`")[1].split("'")[0]
    for l in ss.lemma_names:
      print l, comp
```

but do note that, only 13 synsets were encoded with comparative information in the definition (for `NLTK v.2.0.4`). Also it's not possible to get the hierarchy of the comparative words (e.g. `best > better > good` .

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Pattern library](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern)

It has some useful APIs for your use-case:

```
 from pattern.en import comparative
 comparative(‘cool’)
```

which gives

```
'cooler'
```

Or for superlative degrees

```
from pattern.en import superlative
superlative(‘cool’)
```

which gives

```
'coolest'
```

Web demos : [comparative](http://textanalysisonline.com/pattern-word-comparative) and [superlative](http://textanalysisonline.com/pattern-word-superlative)

Comment: This is the opposite of what is asked.